# Return a list of rowcounts for multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, export, xls

hopefully this will be quick to answer. I'm new to SQL so struggling with this, I may be missing something obvious. I have the below query which returns row counts in separate results however I would like to get the results into an XLS. What is the best method to go about achieving this?

```
select count(*) as "table_1" FROM table_1
select count(*) as "table_2" FROM table_2
select count(*) as "table_3" FROM table_3
select count(*) as "table_4" FROM table_4
select count(*) as "table_5" FROM table_5
select count(*) as "table_6" FROM table_6
select count(*) as "table_7" FROM table_7
select count(*) as "table_8" FROM table_8
select count(*) as "table_9" FROM table_9
select count(*) as "table_10" FROM table_10
```

Many Thanks!

Thanks for the help, here's what I went with to give me what I needed.

I knew it would be something fairly straightforward!

```
SELECT 'table_1' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_1 union all
SELECT 'table_2' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_2 union all
SELECT 'table_3' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_3 union all
SELECT 'table_4' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_4 union all
SELECT 'table_5' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_5 union all
SELECT 'table_6' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_6 union all
SELECT 'table_7' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_7 union all
SELECT 'table_8' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_8 union all
SELECT 'table_9' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_9 union all
SELECT 'table_10' as "Table", count (*) as "Count" FROM table_10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, with the union statement and with sub query's withing your select statment

[Union](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) will merge all the result into one table containing multiple rows

```
select count(*) , 'Table1' as tablename FROM table_1
union all
select count(*), 'Table2' as tablename  FROM table_2
union all
select count(*) ,'Table3' as tablename FROM table_3
.....
.....
```

Sub query's will return one row with multiple columns

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1) as 'Table1',
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2) as 'Table2',
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_3) as 'Table3'
 ......
 ......
```